# Add loaded text to other loaded text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Javascript, to add text to an already existing div I would use

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML + "Text";
```

So that the text that is already present in the div wouldn't be deleted and to be able to reset what is written in the div by just using:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Text";
```

But, since I'm using jquery to load the text from a txt file with

```
$( "#container" ).load( "text.txt" );
```

That doesn't seem possible.

I'm not a big expert on neither JS or Jquery, but is there a way to mix the two to still be able to reset the text in a div or add text to it, while still fetching that text from an external file?

Hope I've been clear enough in explaining what I'm trying to do

Comment: `$( "#container" ).load( "text.txt" );` is correct. The only problem that I seen here is that `text.txt` file is not in the same directory that the page that executes this script. You should define properly the path of the file

Comment: To add to @MarcosPérezGude, your file is also not guaranteed to load, you could wrap it with code to prevent file load error. Since you want to stick with jQuery I would use AJAX

Comment: @MarcosPerezGude how can you see the file is not in the same directory? File-not-found is not the issue, the jQuery `load` is, which replaces the content of the div, removing any previous content.

Comment: uh the file is there on my PC of course, that's not really the problem :)

Comment: I don't understand that, but maybe I'm wrong. I understand that the file doesn't loads. Sorry

Comment: No no, the file does load, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using AJAX to fetch your data but not populate it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'text.txt',
    success: function(text){
         document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += text;
    }
});
```

Ajax is a lot more full featured - it's the 'harder' cousin of `load()`, so you can also add an error catcher (as well as a raft of other things):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'text.txt',
    success: function(text){
         document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += text;
    },
    error: function(e){
         document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += 'Data could not be loaded! (' + e.statusText + ')';
    }
});
```

You can learn more about AJAX at jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This seems to be close to what I'm looking for, but instead of adding the text from the file it's just multyplying the button over and over again

http://puu.sh/lVmz0/04bf5a4685.png

Comment: @Eight Whats in your text file?

Comment: @Eight If its a button, use `value` instead of `innerHTML`, by the way, thats the only reason I can come up with why it would seem to duplicate. UPDATE: I can't duplicate that behaviour.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to be the problem. I'll keep trying to see if I can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could post a bit more HTML to show us what your `#container` element looks like? The above works, I have tested it and it should not duplicate any buttons...

Comment: @Eight My Bad! It's supposed to be `url`, not `src`! Editing now :) Tested and it works now.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

1. You run the risk of loading a file, which may or may not be available. Meaning you could get a file load error. In order to stick with jQuery I would leverage **[AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** to load the file like so:

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "text.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            data.appendTo("#container")
        },
        error: function(e){
            // Show some error, for example:
            alert("Data failed to load from text.txt file")
        }
    });
});
```

2. I believe that **[appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)** will be a much simpler version of what you've tried to accomplish via `document.getElementById("container").innerHTML` in order to replace the text. Give it a try and modify this to work exactly as you like. Let me know if you have any questions about it.
3. To make it clear to you, JQuery is an extension of the existing JavaScript language. Meaning, you can always use your JavaScript within your perceived JQuery code. You can learn how to use the strengths of JQuery to support your JavaScript code with *added functionality*, a great example of one is the AJAX implementation of file loading you see here. To learn more visit: **[Learn JQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)**.